# TFS 2008 to TFS 2010 migration with domain move

Tags: tfs, tfs-migration

I have installed and configured TFS 2010 on a Win 2008 server. I have tested the migration and everything seems o be working fine. I have one issue with the Domain move though.

I am trying to use TFSCONFIG IDENITIES /change command to map the Users in old domain to new domian, but unfortunately the new domain accounts have been added to the TFS group. Hence, I caanott use the Identities /change command.

I am still trying to figure out what needs to be done in order to sync up the accounts b/w two domains. What are my options in this situation? Can I just uninstall and re-install TFS 2010. Would that help me sync up the account names b/w two domains? Please advise

Answer (score 1):

There is [extensive guidance available](http://vsarupgradeguide.codeplex.com/) on the different supported upgrade scenario's.

Probably the easiest way to do the upgrade is to install TFS2010 over the 2008 version and then [do a domain migration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms404883%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). It looks like the issue you're facing is that you added the new account members, instead of migrated the old members to the new ones. I haven't been in that scenario before, you could try removing the new accounts and then migrating, or using the TFS integration tools to migrate all data for one user to another user.

If you still have a backup available, or if the TFS 2008 server is still there, I suggest re-doing the migration, however painful that may be, it will be the safest way to get everything to work again.

Finally there are the The [TFS Integration Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f854dd59-8eeb-4673-8d9a-ae012989bfa2) can be used to migrate from one TFS instance to another, they don't migrate everything, but will migrate the most important things.

Comment: Yes, I have already added the new domain users to TFS after joining TFS to the new domain. Now, I am unable to use tfsconfig identities /change command :(